# The divergence and convergence about integration $ \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^x}{e^{x^\lambda}}\, dx$ when $\lambda>1$

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

I wonder whether this integration is convergent or divergent when $\lambda>1$
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \int^\infty_0 \dfrac{x^x}{e^{x^\lambda}}\,dx =\displaystyle \int^\infty_0 {x^x}{e^{-x^\lambda}}\,dx 
\end{equation}

I can prove that when $\lambda\leq1$ the integration diverges, but when $\lambda>1$ it's difficult for me to decide whether the integration diverges or not.

I tried to split the integration at $x= 1,e,\lambda$ these places, but it doesn't help. Also, I tried to use limit comparison at $x=\infty$, but I can't find a suitable function to do that. Then I tried to find whether there exists a function greater or less than the integrand, but it also doesn't seem to be useful.

I noticed that $x^x$ and $x^\lambda$ are kind of suspicious, but I also don't know if this is a key observation for obtaining the answer.

Thus, any suggestions or help on this? Thanks!

Comment: You can make use of $x^x=e^{x\log x},$ for $x>0.$

Comment: Note that $x^x e^{ - x^\lambda  }  = e^{x\log x} e^{ - x^\lambda  } = \exp \left( { - x^\lambda  \left( {1 - \frac{{\log x}}{{x^{\lambda  - 1} }}} \right)} \right)$ and $\lim _{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{\log x}}{{x^\alpha  }} = 0$ if $\alpha>0$.